# Braintree Transaction Fee

Tags: transactions, braintree, credit-card, fee

I am struggling to find any mention of the Braintree Transaction Fee in the transaction reports.

Braintree fees can seemingly only be found by individual transaction ID in the merchant statement->Transaction Fee Report, however this is only avaliable at month's end and so entirely useless to compare against the daily Braintree disbursements which is the transaction amounts (which can be find via the transaction reports / transaction API) less the Braintree fee.

This transaction fee report is also a separate CSV, so also extremely inconvenient to combine with the transaction API to create custom reports (which is some Braintree themselves recommend).

Is anyone aware of how to get the Transaction Fees (preferably via the API)?

I believe this has been asked for since at least 2016.

Thanks

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm doing my taxes now and I need to list all expenses incurred through Braintree, but the only fee amounts I can see through their transaction export tooling are from PayPal. All credit card transactions lack the fee.

Comment: The only way to do it was to download the transaction fee reports per currency at the end of the month, import the CSVs and do some programmatic manipulation with results from the Transaction API, unfortunately.